# jQuery - Navigation - If specific id is found, do something.

Tags: jquery, function, navigation, find

I cant seem to understand what i'm doing wrong here.

To certain extend my code does work but instead of finding the `id` of the clicked element, it finds all the `id`s

http://jsfiddle.net/34a5b/ - I put it to animate so you can see that it finds `#item1` and then `#item2`

The basic functionality I'm looking for goes like this:

> When li is clicked > find specific id > do the functionality
>   corresponding that specific id

Any ideas on why this doesnt work?

```
    var $Nav= $('#Nav');
    var $Boxee= $('#BoxeeBox');
$Nav.each(function(){
    $(this).find('li').click(function() {
        if( $(this).find('#item1') ){
            $Boxee.animate({ backgroundColor:'blue' });
        }
        if( $(this).find('#item2') ){
            $Boxee.animate({ backgroundColor:'red' });
        }
    });
});
```

Now i wonder why i put $nav.each....

---

I was also trying to figure out more dynamic/simpler way of doing something like that but I couldnt figure that out.. surprise surprise... I'd appreciate if someone could point me to the direction with that one as well ( though I'd still like to know why my code doesnt work )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to loop thru `$Nav`. jQuery click will bind to all `li` if you say `$('#Nav li').click(...)`

Reason for your code to not work is: `$(this).find('#item1')` - here `$(this)` means the `li`, so you're tyring to find `#item1` within itself.

Fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/34a5b/1/

```
var $Nav = $('#Nav li');
var $Boxee = $('#BoxeeBox');
$Nav.click(function() {
    if (this.id == 'item1') {
        $Boxee.animate({
            backgroundColor: 'blue'
        });
    }
    if (this.id == 'item2') {
        $Boxee.animate({
            backgroundColor: 'red'
        });
    }
});
```

Slightly better (performant) version is to use `.delegate` ( http://jsfiddle.net/34a5b/9/ ):

```
$('#Nav').delegate('li', 'click', function() {
        if (this.id == 'item1') {
            $Boxee.animate({
                backgroundColor: 'blue'
            });
        }
        if (this.id == 'item2') {
            $Boxee.animate({
                backgroundColor: 'red'
            });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

In don't know why you are using each function. Following code will do

```
       var $Nav= $('#Nav');
       var $Boxee= $('#BoxeeBox');
       $('#Nav li').click(function() {
           if( $(this).attr('id') == 'item1' ){ 
               $Boxee.animate({ backgroundColor:'blue' });
           }
           else if($(this).attr('id') == 'item2') { 
               $Boxee.animate({ backgroundColor:'red' });
           }
       });
```

check Fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/34a5b/10/